# Interlink among different length scales of simulation and modelling techniques

Tags: reference-request, molecular-modeling, atomistic-simulation

I found this figure:

[image]

In the following paper:

- [A Review on Multiscale Modelling and Simulation for Polymer Nanocomposites](https://www.preprints.org/manuscript/202202.0213/v1)

However, I am skeptical about its correctness, as this paper is not peer-reviewed.

I think:

1. Red is OK
2. blue and green have misleading titles. I should make the green “molecular scale”, and blue should be the “sub-molecular scale”
3. I should remove DFDT  from green
4. I should move Molecular Dynamics (should be abbreviated MD) to green
5. I should move MC to green
6. I should add DFT and QMMD (Quantum Mechanics Molecular Dynamics) do blue

Can anyone supply me with a reference (book or article) so that I can study the correct relationships between various techniques of various scales?

Comment: It is a poorly prepared paper. This might be useful for you https://web.math.princeton.edu/~weinan/papers/weinan_book.pdf. Allen & Tildesley is still going to be one of the best reference books for you though.

Comment: @B.Kelly, Okay but I was looking for a correct classification of the modeling techniques.

Comment: If that is all, then you diagnosed it well enough yourself. You can't really put them in bubbles. You can do Molecular Dynamics and Monte Carlo with DFT, or a force-field, or an isling model etc. QM/MM straddles two bubbles as it is, you can't shove it into molecular or electronic - I would almost forget about bubbles and just learn the techniques and use them as creatively and appropriately as you can.

Comment: @B.Kelly, *If that is all, then you diagnosed it well enough yourself.* --- However, in order to use a similar diagram in my writings, I need a reference to be used in the bibliography.

Comment: If you want scales, then a better place would be label Electrons>>nuclei>>functionals(coarse graining), meso'

Comment: @B.Kelly Maybe you can just write an answer? :)

Comment: @user366312 do you really need to copy a diagram, rather than create your own? If it were me, I'd make my own and then add something like "Figure adapted from Sharma and Devi [3], using updated classification categories".